# How to count random appearing values on random index position of array

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say that I have array of any size. Due to 'some operation', on random index of array start appearing number 20. This 20 value could be any other defined value but for an example, let it be 20. So if I have array `int a[]={1,2,3,4,5..,10}`and I do something, array would be int `a[]={20,2,20,20,5,..,10}`. And lets say that I have three counters called `int a, int b, int c;`.

Counter `int a` -> is only increased by one, if value which was replaced by 20 was 1.

Counter `int b` -> is only increased by one, if value which was replaced by 20 was 3.

Counter `int c` -> is only increased by one, if value which was replaced by 20 was 4.

***Counter could be on any value, not only* 1,3,4**

Then, when I choose random index from array which holds the value 20, I want to increase correct **counter** by one. So, if I get random index [0] I want to increase counter `int a` by one.

How can I do something like that? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want this to work for **all** values or only for values `1`, `3` and `4`? Also is the array always initialized in the way described in the post?

Comment: @Turing85 for all values :)..lets say that value 20 can be any other value

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add this requirement.

Comment: @Turing85 question updated, ps. array is defined always with same numbers, only specific value '20-let say' is then appearing on random index of array

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use a series of `if` statements or a `switch` statement.

```
int[] array ={1,2,3,4,5,...,10};
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(array.length); //random index
switch(array[index]){
    case 1: ++a; break;
    case 3: ++b; break;
    case 4: ++c; break;
}
array[index] = 20;
```

It is simpler to use a `Map`, and it is easier to generalize the algorithm with this data structure.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
count.merge(array[index], 1, Integer::sum);
array[index] = 20;
// use count.getOrDefault(1, 0) to get the number of elements whose 
// values were 1 before being changed to 20
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but If I would have array of 200 numbers, I think that this solution would not be the best way..should I mention this in question

Comment: use the `Map`-approach then in conjunction with a loop.